# Implement carousel in salesforce b2c commerce cloud

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I am Salesforce commmerce cloud developer , I want to build a product card carousel on salesforce but it is really hard to implement carousel in business manager since we cannot use react libraries or external libraries. I have worked on react earlier and really new to salesforce so this really challenging for me.
Any help or suggestions on this would be really helpfull.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you can use slick carousel. it is widely used across the SFCC website and it is quite easy to implement.